# Definition of POS tag and Dependency label sets are used within Parsey McParseface?

Tags: pos-tagger, syntaxnet, dependency-parsing, parsey-mcparseface

The POS tags and Depedency labels output by `Parsey McParseface` are given in the `tag-set` and `label-set` files [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/models/parsey_mcparseface) respectively.

The `Syntaxnet` readme outlines that the model was trained on the Penn Treebank, OntoNotes and the English Web Treebanks.

Is there a detailed description of the corresponding POS tags and Dependency labels used in these treebanks similar to that given by the [Universal Dependency project](http://universaldependencies.org/u/dep/all.html)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a bit more searching, it looks like the Stanford dependency grammar detailed [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf) and POS tags detailed [here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bies/manuals/tagguide.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for this!  Great to have this specific question and answer here - saved me time!